# Complex SQL query (suggestions needed)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

Could someone throw me ideas about how to resolve the following issue:

I have pictures, videos and tags in my database. Tags can be associated to pictures and videos. I have to query database for tag IDs and count that are modified before 7 days or earlier and sort them by count of associations they have to picture and video assets.

So the idea is that at the end I can output the tags that were associated to pictures or videos the most during last 7 days. I wrote down the DB structure with the fields I have

```
VIDEO
    ID

PICTURE
    ID

PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING
    CS_OWNERID  (ID of picture)
    CS_ATTRID  ( will store ID of the tag attribute (picture_tag or video_tag))
    ASSETVALUE ( will store ID OF THE associated tag)

VIDEO_ATTRMAPPING
    CS_OWNERID  (ID of video)
    CS_ATTRID  ( will store ID of the tag attribute (picture_tag or video_tag))
    ASSETVALUE ( will store ID OF THE associated tag)

TAG
    ID
    UPDATEDATE

ATTRIBUTES (picture_tag attribute ID is stored here)
    ID
    NAME
```

So we can see that tags, videos, picture and attributes are stored in separate tables. We can tell that tag is referenced by video or picture (in other words, video/picture has a tag association) if VIDEO/PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING table has record with video or picture tag attribute id in CS_ATTRID column and id of the tag in ASSETVALUE column.

I am assuming it will be query with sub-queries, so I started to break this task in sub-tasks and figure out how to obtain all the information that's needed.

I will definitely have to get the ID of the tag attributes for video and picture objects:

```
SELECT id FROM ATTRIBUTES WHERE NAME = 'picture_tag' OR NAME = 'video_tag'
```

Also an example of how I can query for tags that are n days old:

```
SELECT id FROM TAG WHERE updateddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-08-20 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND CURRENT_DATE
```

This probably isn't that complex as it seems, however, I am not sure about how the whole query should look like and with what to start. Could someone throw an idea or sample?

I am using oracle, but am familiar with mysql too, so samples from any of the DBMSs would be great. Let me know if I made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The tags that were updated in the last 7 days can be written as:

```
select id from tags where updatedate >= sysdate - 7
```

From what you're saying the ATTRIBUTES table only has two values in it; so you can ignore it. Even if it has more your tables PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING and VIDEO_ATTRMAPPING ensure that the attributes are enforced when you join to them so this doesn't matter either.

If you want a tag to be associated to a picture or a video you just need to enforce that it exists in one of the *_ARRTMAPPING tables:

```
select *
  from tags t
  left outer join picture_attrmappings pa
    on t.id = pa.assetvalue
  left outer join video_attrmappings va
    on t.id = va.assetvalue
 where t.updatedate >= sysdate - 7
   and ( pa.assetvalue is not null
         or va.assetvalue is not null
         )
```

You then want the tag IDs that have been modified most; so you need to ORDER BY the count:

```
select t.id
  from tags t
  left outer join picture_attrmappings pa
    on t.id = pa.assetvalue
  left outer join video_attrmappings va
    on t.id = va.assetvalue
 where t.updatedate >= sysdate - 7
   and ( pa.assetvalue is not null
         or va.assetvalue is not null
         )
 group by t.id
 order by count(*) desc
```

---

On a slightly different note this is quite a strange schema (assuming you've left nothing out). I would expect PICTURE_ATTRMAPPINGS to be a junction table between TAGS and PICTURE. 
The TAGS table should store a unique list of tags but this doesn't seem to be what it does. The UPDATEDATE should then be in either PICTURE_ARRTMAPPINGS as you can then know when each tag was last updated or in PICTURE so you know when all tags were last updated (or both).

I suspect you're missing some of the schema but I see no method, with what you've provided, of using either PICTURE or VIDEO.

Answer (score 0):

all tag ids assigned to the pictures:

```
SELECT ASSETVALUE  
            FROM PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING 
                 JOIN ATTRIBUTES 
                 ON (      ATTRIBUTES.ID = PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING.CS_ATTRID 
                      AND  ATTRIBUTES.NAME = 'picture_tag'
                    )
```

all tag ids assigned to the videos:

```
    SELECT ASSETVALUE  
    FROM   VIDEO_ATTRMAPPING 
           JOIN ATTRIBUTES 
           ON (      ATTRIBUTES.ID = PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING.CS_ATTRID 
                AND  ATTRIBUTES.NAME = 'video_tag'
              )
```

use OUTER JOIN to count pictures and videos wich are tagged

```
SELECT 
  TAG.ID
, SUM(CASE WHEN PT.ASSETVALUE is not NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tagged_picture_number
, SUM(CASE WHEN VT.ASSETVALUE is not NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tagged_vieos_number
  FROM 
    TAG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT ASSETVALUE  
        FROM PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING 
             JOIN ATTRIBUTES 
             ON ( ATTRIBUTES.ID = PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING.CS_ATTRID AND  ATTRIBUTES.NAME = 'picture_tag') 
      ) PT
      ON ( PT.ASSETVALUE = TAG.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT ASSETVALUE  
        FROM   VIDEO_ATTRMAPPING 
               JOIN ATTRIBUTES 
               ON ( ATTRIBUTES.ID = PICTURE_ATTRMAPPING.CS_ATTRID AND  ATTRIBUTES.NAME = 'video_tag') 
      ) VT
      ON ( PT.ASSETVALUE = TAG.ID)
WHERE
    TAG.UPDATEDATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') - 7
group by TAG.ID
order by tagged_picture_number + tagged_vieos_number DESC
;
```